# $T:V→V$ is a linear transformation such that $T\circ T(x)$ is invertible. Prove that $T$ is also invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse

Let $V$ be a vector space with dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $T:V→V$ a linear transformation such that $T\circ T(x)$ is invertible. Prove that $T$ is also invertible.

I'm thinking to use the Theorem that states: If $T:V→W$ is an invertible linear transformation with inverse $T^{-1}:W→V$, then $T^{-1}$ is a linear transformation.

Any tips on how I should go about this problem?

Comment: how would that theorem help you? I think the easiest way to go about this is via injectivity&surjectivity.

Comment: $T(x)=0\implies T\circ T(x)=0\implies x=0\implies T$ is injective, also $T\circ T$ invertible implies $T$ is surjective.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**:

For any maps $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y\to Z$,

- $g\circ f$ injective implies $f$ injective,
- $g\circ f$ surjective implies $g$ surjective.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\det(T^2)=(\det T)^2$.

Comment: With a 33.6k reputation, it wouldn't hurt you to know some basics of MathJax and LaTeX such as this: $\rm{det} T,$ coded as `\rm{det} T`, looks different from $\det T,$ coded as `\det T`. Note the space between $\det$ and $T$ in the latter, and the fact that `\rm` affects whatever comes after it including the letter T. And note the difference in space to the right of $\det$ in $\det T$ and $\det(T),$ coded respectively as `\det T` and `\det(T)`. And note the lack of spacing in things like $\text{det}T,$ coded as `\text{det}T`. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks.  I didn't know if `\det` would work.

Answer (score 1):

If $T\circ T$ has inverse then exists $S$ which gives  $(T\circ T)\circ S=1\!\!1$, but if  we use composition's associativity then $T\circ (T\circ S)=1\!\!1$ too, therefore $T$ has inverse, which is $T\circ S$.

Answer (score 1):

A proof by contraposition is swift and easy:

Suppose $T$ were *not* invertible; then

$\exists V \ni x \ne 0, \; Tx = 0; \tag 1$

then

$T^2(x) = T(Tx) = T(0) = 0,  \tag 2$

and thus $T^2$ is not invertible either.

Now taking the contrapositive yields the desired result.